# How to add video url to a Jekyll no js lightbox

Tags: ruby, jekyll, lightbox

There is a lightbox sans JavaScript in a Jekyll theme and I have been trying to add url capability to click on image or title and play a YouTube video within it.
Where is the code that includes the elements of the lightbox? In the yml file it has

add:
image: “”
title:””
description:””

And I was hoping to place url: “”
At the end but when I do Jekyll won’t build.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your post. It should include your exact inputs, exact outputs, and detailed steps you took so that the problem can be reproduced by others.

Comment: just get it from github.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Works really well where you might want a video to show up in the lightbox instead of an enlarged image. Jekyll had no problem.

```
--
```

name: "animation"
arts:

## Row 1

- image: "images/galleries/animation/some.png"
  order: "1"
  artist: "Name"
  title: "Something"
  description: place the embed youtube iframe here